# Power management problem on Samsung SI9000?

Tags: battery-charging

I have a Samsung SI9000 model SPH-D710 Sprint version. The issue I am having is the phone seems to not be charging the battery. Currently the battery is fully discharged and when plugged in and charging the phone charging icon on the screen appears and disappears quickly and then the phone shuts off.

I checked the voltage at the USB port and I see 5V. I also check the voltage at the battery pin connection and I see 2.8V. I'm not sure if that is the correct voltage to be seen at the pin connection that's why I am asking this question.

Also, the battery I am using is a Anker 3.7V 1800mAH battery. I do not have another battery to rule out if its a faulty battery.

Comment: If you can't even conclude that 2.8 V is too low for a 3.7 V battery then you shouldn't even be messing with this. Just go to a phone repair shop and see what they can do for you. Anyway your phone is ancient, it is probably time to get a newer model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frequent problem with charging a phone over u-USB connector is contamination by lint, which leads to excessive plug forcing, which might bend data pins in the tiny flimsy connector. Once the data are pins are broken, the phone loses ability to identify chargers and doesn't charge itself anymore. The level of 2.8 V no load is definitely too low for a Li-Po 3.7-V battery.

You might need to find a replacement sub-assembly board that holds the USB connector. Or get a stand-alone charger and keep charging your battery separately.

Comment: Thanks, I did have problems with the USB connector on the phone. Didn't know above stand alone charging.